# Broadcom adapter continuously freezes then works

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I have a problem with my Lenovo G580 running 16.04 (or 18.04 from bootable USB).If I am just surfing then every thing is fine, but if I am downloading using Deluge or Transmission or Youtube then the internet freezes for 1 to 2 minutes. If I am in Firefox or Chrome then any site that I try to use will hang until the freeze period is over. I cannot find  similar questions, because many of the "freeze" answers require a reboot, but this is a case of the freeze reoccurring every 5 minutes or so. The "txop exceeded" messages occur often.

Thank you.

Some technical details:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0587]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

*/etc/network/interfaces* text file contains the following:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

---

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

`dmesg` messages with "bcrm"

```
[    4.132179] brcmsmac bcma0:1: mfg 4bf core 812 rev 24 class 0 irq 17
[    4.138148] ieee80211 phy0: registered radio enabled led device: brcmsmac-phy0:radio gpio: 499
[    4.158925] Modules linked in: arc4 brcmsmac cordic brcmutil b43 mac80211 cfg80211 ssb snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_codec_conexant coretemp snd_hda_codec_generic kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_intel crc32_pclmul snd_hda_codec ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_core pcbc snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd snd_seq_midi glue_helper snd_seq_midi_event cryptd intel_cstate snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_perf input_leds joydev serio_raw snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer lpc_ich snd bcma shpchp soundcore mei_me mei ideapad_laptop sparse_keymap wmi mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb hid_generic usbhid hid i915 i2c_algo_bit psmouse drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ahci drm libahci alx mdio
[    4.278318] brcmsmac bcma0:1 wlp2s0b1: renamed from wlan0
[    5.126726] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[    5.126778] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[    6.714474] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[    6.714480] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[    6.715574] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 159/256 dur 1778/1504
[    6.718657] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 137/256 dur 1602/1504
[    7.517411] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
```

Comment: Did you try to install `bcmwl-kernel-source`. I know that it had problems with rev 01, but it is worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist b43" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and report your results.

Comment: I tried the blacklist 4 commands but this did not solve the problem. After a number of different download combinations, I would say that these blacklist commands have made the freeze period occur even more often.  Forgot to mention that my phone wireless connected to the same modem works perfectly during the ubuntu freeze period.